# Zabbix: add variable/macro in "Query fields" on web scenarios or item

Tags: url, get, monitoring, zabbix

I'm studying zabbix, but I'm having some troubles with my scenario.

I'm monitoring some urls (GET method), basically it's applications that returns me a json call. One of then returns me a token that changes all the time, and I have to use this token in my other applications. I'm monitoring it all by web scenarios, so I parse my url querys in "Query fields" (Web scenarios -> Scenario -> Steps) and, as I said, I have a "token" query too in all my apis. My problem is that in the field "Value" of then, I need to put this variable token there, because I need a valid token all the time.

I already have the token result working on Zabbix, I just want to know how to call this in "value" field of web scenarios steps query fields. There's a way to do this?

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an item value and reference it into another item key.

You can use a macro value, but you have to update it somehow.

A workaround, not nice but should do the trick:

You can write a script (python api are quite simple) that makes the first query, then update a macro with the token value: for example write "xxxxxxxx" into `{$TOKEN}`
Or, you can setup a http agent that makes the first query, then use a python script to take this value and write it into the macro.

Your http agent item(s) should reference the corresponding token in the header section.

Of course you'll need to schedule your script(s) and your http agent items correctly: you must be sure that the correct token is written into the macro **before** checking the items!